# How to select unique combination of 2 columns in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

For example if i have this table of messages and it has this 3 columns

```
╔══════════╦══════════╦══════════╦══════════╦
║ from_user║ to_user  ║ message  ║    date  ║
╠══════════╬══════════╣══════════║══════════║
║ 1        ║ 2        ║ text     ║timestamp ║
║ 1        ║ 3        ║ text     ║   ..     ║
║ 2        ║ 1        ║ text     ║   ..     ║
║ 2        ║ 3        ║ text     ║   ..     ║
║ 3        ║ 1        ║ text     ║   ..     ║
║ 1        ║ 2        ║ text     ║   ..     ║
║ 1        ║ 4        ║ text     ║   ..     ║
║ 3        ║ 1        ║ text     ║   ..     ║
╚══════════╩══════════╩══════════╩══════════╩
```

I want to get all where a user is involved, if i wanted to select all conversations user 1 had (all records where he is in in column "from _user" AND where he is in "to_user) this "conversations" would be:

1. Conversation between user 1 and 2
2. Conversation between user 1 and 3
3. Conversation between user 1 and 4

So i would get only 1 record (the last one) of each of this conversations ordered by date

```
╔══════════╦══════════╦══════════╦══════════╦
║ from_user║ to_user  ║ message  ║    date  ║
╠══════════╬══════════╣══════════║══════════║
║ 1        ║ 2        ║ text     ║timestamp ║
║ 1        ║ 3        ║ text     ║   ..     ║
║ 2        ║ 1        ║ text     ║   ..     ║
║ 2        ║ 3        ║ text     ║   ..     ║
║ 3        ║ 1        ║ text     ║   ..     ║
║ 1        ║ 2        ║ text     ║   ..     ║<--- i would get this one third (conv between 1&2)
║ 2        ║ 3        ║ text     ║   ..     ║
║ 1        ║ 4        ║ text     ║   ..     ║<--- i would get this one second (conv between 1&4)
║ 3        ║ 1        ║ text     ║   ..     ║<--- i would get this one first (conv between 1&3)
╚══════════╩══════════╩══════════╩══════════╩
```

I'm unsure as to how to solve this, should i use GROUP BY ?

EDIT: a conversation is when a user sends or receives a message, a conversation can have multiple messages or just a single one.
The ones i marked that i wanted to get as a result are the last record of each of this conversations, it doesn't matter who sent it and who received it i want the last record of each of the conversation a user had.

This attempt is the closest i can get to what i want

```
SELECT id, from_user, to_user
FROM messages 
WHERE (to_user = '$usr_id' OR from_user = '$usr_id') AND id IN
(
    SELECT MAX(id)
    FROM messages
    GROUP BY from_user, to_user
)
```

but i'm getting the last record of each of the combinations, for example if had

```
id  from_user  to_user
1       1          2
2       1          3
3       4          1
4       2          1
5       1          2
```

the output is:

```
id  from_user  to_user
1       1          2
2       1          3
3       4          1
4       2          1
```

As you can see the record with id of 5 wasn't selected because it's repeated but the records with id 1 and 4 are the same conversation and only one of them should be outputed

Comment: please clarify: the order you show in the last table is based on a date which is not present in the table or some other criteria? what happens to (1,3) and (2,1)? they occur only once. nd (2,1) occurs twice but you chose it...

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs and the desired result

Comment: I added column for date, it doesn't matter how many times they occur as explained in the edit. What do you mean i chose it?

Answer (score 1):

For readability purposes, I'll show you a first query that gives the results you want, except if the queried user is on the to_user column:

```
SELECT   from_user, to_user, max(msg_date) latest, id
FROM     messages 
WHERE    to_user = 1 
      OR from_user = 1
GROUP BY from_user, to_user
ORDER BY latest desc;
```

To get this solved using group by, you need to switch the from_user, to_user column values when your user is on the to_user side. You might also need a flag, "switched", to indicate these cases. So, what you need is:

```
SELECT id, main_user, other_user, switched, max(msg_date) latest, msg_date, msg
FROM   (SELECT id, 1 main_user, if (from_user = 1, to_user, from_user) other_user,
               if (from_user=1, 0, 1) switched, msg_date, msg
        FROM   messages 
        WHERE  to_user = 1 
            OR from_user = 1) user_messages
GROUP BY main_user, other_user
ORDER BY msg_date desc;
```

In this same query, you can use "switched" to put back from_user, to_user, using IF like in the subquery. I didn't put it now to make it easier to read.

Comment: I've clarified some things and corrected a few other. Mainly i want to select all conversations where a particular user is involved.